# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Tag'

Tags: python, postgresql

Traceback (most recent call last):
https://retailer.partykungen.se/sjalvlysande-armband.html
  File "C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/crawler/back-end.py", line 121, in 
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO crawler(url, title, varient, category, comments, price, description, tag, image, article, stock, is_retailer) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',(link, titl, name1, cat, comments, price, description, tag, image, art, stock, is_retailer))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Tag'

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, what you tried and what failed. Also what you expect to see as a result.

Comment: Something to do with the data you are trying to insert into tag field, turn on logging to see the value received at Postgesql if you think it looks ok. If you capture the sql you can then try some variations while directly applying the sql in PGadmin

Answer (score 1):

Like above, I would check your data. So if you are trying to import a pandas dataframe into a Postgres Table I would do the following:

Make sure you have stripped out all tags completely. So thoroughly check that first by examining your dataframe as the Tags throw off the psycopg2 driver as it is unable to recognise the object correctly. So make sure you extract all the information you need from HTML first. Use getText() to obtain the more 'stubborn' tags.

```
    list_titles = []
    movie_titles = all_movies[n].find_all("h1",{"class":"blah"})
    for k in movie_titles:
        title = k.getText()
        list_titles.append(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a TypeError conflict between how you defined your data types in your PostgreSQL table and your parser object return type.

For example, using BeautifulSoup4 (bs4) to crawl through your file, the return type of an element in your tree is of **type: Tag** (see: "Kind of Objects" in the [bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)).

My suggestion:

1) Define all your Postgre Table types as text (to test successful insertion during debugging)

2) Convert all your variables to strings: e.g.,

```
... (str(link), str(titl), str(name1), ...)
```

3) This should get you a successful insertion, then you can walk backwards making sure each element matches the types you need in your table.